# How to add pixel referenced rectangles to a georeferenced raster image

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am using AI to detect images in a georeferenced photo that is say 4500 by 3000 pixels.  The AI gives me bounding boxes that surround the images it has detected and provides a text file with bounding box coordinates in x,y using the number of pixels from the upper left corner of the photo as the reference point.  It gives the upper left and lower right points of the bounding box in x,y and the width and height in pixels as well.  For example one bounding box would be defined by

(3156, 2256, 3188, 2285), w: 32, h:29

I could have hundreds of these bounding boxes for a single georeferenced photo.  In QGIS, how do I georeference the bounding boxes and link them to the georeferenced photo as perhaps an attribute table?

Comment: Do you have any experience with GDAL/OGR? I suggest you get the geotransform from the raster as your origin and then offset by the pixel bounds to get your world coordinates but write the bounding boxes to a vector layer instead, if you've got potentially thousands of boxes your raster could end up being very messy.